# Microelectronic Circuits SEDRA/SMITH Multisim

Tags: multisim, pspice

I'm reading Microelectronic Circuits written by Sedra and Smith. There is plenty of examples and problems to solve which include using Multisim and PSpice. However I'm using the newest software (version 13.0) and unfotunately files on CD from textbook were created in older version (probably 10.0). Is there any possibility to run these examples?

Anybody read this text book and run all examples? Why PSpice problem sets were created to different exercises comparing to Multisim files?

Regards

Comment: Have you tried running these older files?

Comment: Yep. And I'm getting dialog box which tells me it cannot run older files.

Comment: I find the Agilent Technologies 344 page "Netlist Translator for SPICE and Spectre" book useful in handling situations where I have different SPICE species files and have to do manual translation. This link is still good as of this posting: http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/ads2005a/pdf/netlist.pdf (I didn't think this comment rose to the level of an answer).

Answer (score 1):

*Why PSpice problems were created to different exercises comparing to Multisim files?*

At first, I do not understand this question. Where are problems created ?

Secondly, I would not recommend to use the existing files on CD. The larning effect is rather limited because you do nothing else than to run some existing files and programs without knowing what`s really going on.

Instead, I recommend to create your own simulation profile based on the examples given (circuit diagrams and/or small signal equivalent diagrams). So you can - for example - switch between real and idealized opamp models and evaluate the differences.

Comment: I mean exercises created in Multisim corresponds to different parts of the book. However, at the beginning of the textbook a reader is encouraged to choose between these two programs - PSpice or Multisim.
I don't see difference in learning from ready-to-simulation files and these ones created by myself. The only difference I think is waste of time to create new ones.